# How does newCachedThreadPool cache thread

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

Per the comment of method `public static ExecutorService newCachedThreadPool()` in `Executor` Class:

```
Threads that have not been used for sixty seconds are terminated and 
removed from the **cache**.
```

I was wondering where is the cache and how it functions? As I didn't see any possible static `Collection` variable in the `ThreadPoolExecutor` or it's super class.

Comment: Why would you expect it to be static?

Comment: It is `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor#workers` collection. Why do you think is must be static?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically `Worker` is a `Runnable` containing a reference to a `Thread` and not a `Thread` by itself.

Let us dig deeper into the mechanics of this class.

`Executors.cachedThreadPool` uses this constructor from `ThreadPoolExecutor`

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                                      60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                                      new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
```

where 60s corresponds to the `keepAliveTime` time.

### **Worker Addition / Task submission**

A `RunnableFuture` is created out of the submitted `Callable` or `Runnable`.
This is passed down to the `execute()` method.

The `execute` method tries to insert the task on to the `workQueue` which in our case is the `SynchronousQueue`. This will fail and return false due to the semantics of `SynchronousQueue`.
   (Just hold on to this thought, we will revisit this when we talk about caching aspect)

The call goes on to the `addIfUnderMaximumPoolSize` method within `execute` which will create a `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.Worker` runnable and creates a Thread and adds the created `Worker` to the `workers` hashSet. (the one others have mentioned in the answers)

and then it calls the `thread.start()` .

The run method of Worker is very important and should be noted.

```
public void run() {
    try {
        Runnable task = firstTask;
        firstTask = null;
        while (task != null || (task = getTask()) != null) {
            runTask(task);
            task = null;
        }
    } finally {
        workerDone(this);
    }
}
```

**At this point in time you have a submitted a task and a thread is created and running it.**

### **Worker Removal**

In the `run` method if you have noticed there is a while loop.
It is an incredibly interesting piece of code.

If the task is not null it will short circuit and not check for the second condition.

Once the task has run using `runTask` and the task reference is set to null, the call comes to the second check condition which takes it into `getTask` method.

Here is the part which decides a worker should be purged or not.

```
workQueue.poll(keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
```

The workQueue is polled for a minute in this case to check for any new tasks coming on the queue.
If not it will return null and checks for whether worker can exit.

Returning null means we will break out of the while and come to the `finally` block.

Here the worker is removed from the HashSet and the referenced Thread is also gone.

### Caching aspect

Coming back to the SynchronousQueue we discussed in Task submission.

In the event I submit a task where `workerQueue.offer` and `workerQueue.poll` is able to work in tandem, i.e. there is a task to process in between those 60s I can re-use the thread.

This can be seen in action if I put a sleep of 59s vs 61s between my each task execution.

*for 59s I can see the thread getting re-used. for 61s I can see a new thread getting created in the pool.*

N.B. The actual timings could vary from machine to machine and my `run()` is just printing out `Thread.currentThread().getName()`

Please let me know in comments if I have missed something or misinterpreted the code.

Comment: Regardless of the other code, the while loop you mentioned above and SynchronousQueue make the threadpool reuse-able and infinitely alive,right? And the submitted task is actually cached in **HashSet<Worker> workers**, right?

Comment: *not* regardless of other code. The key is the polling part in the workQueue. Read the Worker Removal section to understand how workers are removed. Also do the 59s vs 61s exercise.

Comment: If the first task submitted and processed meanwhile there is no more tasks submitted in 60s or much more than 1 min, the created thread will be gc(). But who holds the reference of **HashSet<Worker> workers**? if there is no reference to workers, how could it cache the thread?

Comment: The reference to the workers is from the `ThreadPoolExecutor` instance which won't be gc'ed until the executor is shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

`Cache` word is only an abstraction. Internally it uses `HashSet` to hold Threads. As per the code:

```
/**
 * Set containing all worker threads in pool. Accessed only when
 * holding mainLock.
 */
private final HashSet<Worker> workers = new HashSet<Worker>();
```

And if at all you are interested about the runnables you `submit` or `execute`.

`newCachedThreadPool` uses `SynchronousQueue<Runnable>` to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

If you go through the code of [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), you will see this:

```
 /**
 * Set containing all worker threads in pool. Accessed only when
 * holding mainLock.
 */
private final HashSet<Worker> workers = new HashSet<Worker>();
```

and this:

```
/**
 * The queue used for holding tasks and handing off to worker
 * threads.  We do not require that workQueue.poll() returning
 * null necessarily means that workQueue.isEmpty(), so rely
 * solely on isEmpty to see if the queue is empty (which we must
 * do for example when deciding whether to transition from
 * SHUTDOWN to TIDYING).  This accommodates special-purpose
 * queues such as DelayQueues for which poll() is allowed to
 * return null even if it may later return non-null when delays
 * expire.
 */
private final BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue;
```

And this:

```
 try {
          Runnable r = timed ?
               // here keepAliveTime is passed as sixty seconds from
               // Executors#newCachedThreadPool()
               workQueue.poll(keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) :
               workQueue.take();
           if (r != null)
                return r;
           timedOut = true;
        } catch (InterruptedException retry) {
            timedOut = false;
        }
```

I sincere walk through the actual implementation code, keeping these pointers in mind will help you understand more clearly.